# Bind this when using method decorators in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decorator, ecmascript-next

How to bind `this` with `transform-decorators-legacy` Babel plugin?
For example I have some simple decorator. Decorator works, but `this` is undefined on component's method.

```
fucntion myDecorator(target, name, descriptor) {
    var oldValue = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function() {
        ...// Doing some stuff here I need the decorator for
        ...// (for example logging on every method call)
        return oldValue.apply(null, arguments);
    };

    return descriptor;

}

class MyClass extends React.Component {
    @myDecorator
    myMethod() {
        ...// this.props... is unavailable here(`this` is undefined)
    }
}
```

If I try to use @myDecorator with some [@autobind](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator/blob/master/src/index.js) decorators I get
`TypeError: Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute`, because

> A data descriptor is a property that has a value, which may or may not be writable. An accessor descriptor is a property described by a getter-setter pair of functions. A descriptor must be one of these two flavors; it cannot be both.

In my example I can not use `value()` and `get()`.

Binding in the constructor (`this.myMethod = thid.myMethod.bind(this)`) doesn't seem to be helpful either, because you bind undecorated method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not the problem with `.bind`ing decorated methods.

But there is something that you missed. Even though you did `.bind` your `myMethod` inside your `constructor` to the class, when you invoke it, no matter from where, `myDecorator` modifies the execution scope.

`oldValue.apply(null, arguments)`

Basically, you replaced target scope (`MyClass`) with `null`.

So what you want is this:

`oldValue.apply(this, arguments)`

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/0n6v1dtp/

Comment: Doing as you suggested, `this` is pointing to `React.Component` and not to `MyClass`

Comment: Hmm, seems to work. Funny thing, I'm 100% sure I've tried the same approach and it wasn't working, with `this` being `undefined`. Could you please explain why did you need the line `props = this.props`?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed to solve this:
Using code from mentioned [@autobind](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator/blob/master/src/index.js) decorator:

```
function myDecorator(target, key, descriptor) {
    let fn = descriptor.value;

    return {
        configurable: true,

        get() {
            let boundFn = fn.bind(this);
            Reflect.defineProperty(this, key, {
                value: boundFn,
                configurable: true,
                writable: true
            });

            return function() {
                ...// Doing some stuff here I need the decorator for
                ...// (for example logging on every method call)
                return boundFn.apply(this, arguments)
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is necessary, instead you can just do this: `var oldValue = descriptor.value; descriptor.value = function() { return oldValue.apply(this, arguments); } return descriptor;` Check the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: This is because your first bind to `this` in the constructor of your example. This will not work for decorators that require parameters.